# how to add 'item_qty' if the 'item_id' matches, and store the new result in an array?

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, associative-array

```
$arr = array(
    0 => array('item_id' => 13,
               'item_qty' => 3,
    ),
    1 => array('item_id' => 10,
               'item_qty' => 7,
    ),
    2 => array('item_id' => 13,
               'item_qty' => 2,
    ),
    3 => array('item_id' => 10,
               'item_qty' => 4,
    ),
    4 => array('item_id' => 10,
               'item_qty' => 4,
    ),
);
```

how to add `item_qty` if the `item_id` matches, and store the new result in an array?

Comment: please show what you have tried and what is your expected output

Comment: Is that how you would ask a colleague or a friend? Just throwing random stuff on their table and expecting an answer? Please read http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve and http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow, can you please show us an example of what exactly you want to achieve and show us what you have already tried?

Comment: Where is your code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is what you need . loop the array and set item_id as key to new array and check if already item_id is isset add the quantity with existing quantity like this .

```
    <?php

    $arr = array ( 0 => array ( 'item_id' => 13 , 'item_qty' => 3 ), 
                  1 => array ( 'item_id' => 10 , 'item_qty' => 7 ),
                  2 => array ( 'item_id' => 13, 'item_qty' => 2 ), 
                  3 => array ( 'item_id' => 10 ,'item_qty' => 4 ), 
                  4 => array ( 'item_id' => 10 ,'item_qty' => 4 ));

    $new_array =array();

    foreach($arr as $key=>$row)
    {

       $new_array[$row['item_id']]=isset($new_array[$row['item_id']])? array('item_id'=>$row['item_id'],'item_qty'=>$row['item_qty']+$new_array[$row['item_id']]['item_qty']) : $row;   
    }

    echo "<pre>";
    print_r($new_array);

    ?>
```

Output :

```
    Array
    (
        [13] => Array
            (
                [item_id] => 13
                [item_qty] => 5
            )

        [10] => Array
            (
                [item_id] => 10
                [item_qty] => 15
            )

    )
```

**Update 1**

Use  [array_values](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-values.php) to reset the array key.

```
        Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [item_id] => 13
                    [item_qty] => 5
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [item_id] => 10
                    [item_qty] => 15
                )

        )
```

Comment: could you please explain the code? It works fine. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Just loop over it, put all the IDs as keys in a new array, and add values where the keys match.

```
$output = array();
foreach ($arr as $v) {
    if (!array_key_exists($v['item_id'], $output))
        $output[$v['item_id']] = $v['item_qty'];
    else
        $output[$v['item_id']] += $v['item_qty'];
}
```

[**Live demo**](https://3v4l.org/tJbD5)

Output of `$output` with your array would be

> Array
>   (
>       [13] => 5
>       [10] => 15
>   )

where the key represents the ID and the values the quantity.

Answer (score 0):

try do something like this

```
function add_value($arr, $itemId)
{
    foreach($arr as $k => $v)
    {
        if ($v['item_id'] == $itemId)
        {
            $arr[$k]['item_qty']++;
        }
    }

    return $arr;
}

var_dump(add_value($arr,10));
```

Result:

```
$arr = array ( 0 => array ( 'item_id' => 13 , 'item_qty' => 3 ), 1 => array ( 'item_id' => 10 , 'item_qty' => 8 ), 2 => array ( 'item_id' => 13, 'item_qty' => 2 ), 3 => array ( 'item_id' => 10 ,'item_qty' => 5 ), 4 => array ( 'item_id' => 10 ,'item_qty' => 5 ), );
```

Answer (score 0):

i think you want like this

```
$item_id = 10;
$test = [];
foreach ($arr as $key => $value) {
    if($value['item_id'] == $item_id){
        $value['item_qty'] += 10;
    }
    array_push($test, $value);
}
print_r($test);
```

Result like this

```
Array ( [0] => Array ( [item_id] => 13 [item_qty] => 3 ) [1] => Array ( [item_id] => 10 [item_qty] => 17 ) [2] => Array ( [item_id] => 13 [item_qty] => 2 ) [3] => Array ( [item_id] => 10 [item_qty] => 14 ) [4] => Array ( [item_id] => 10 [item_qty] => 14 ) )
```